# Unable to unmarshall response (weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryXMLInputFactory cannot be cast to javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

ReceiveMessageRequest receiveMessageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest()
.withQueueUrl(queueUrl).withVisibilityTimeout(10).withMaxNumberOfMessages(10);

```
        List<Message> message1  = sqs.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest).getMessages();
```

getting this exception:--
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to unmarshall response (weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryXMLInputFactory cannot be cast to javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory). Response Code: 200, Response Text: OK
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1651)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1336)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1113)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:726)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:668)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:532)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:512)
at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.doInvoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2215)
at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2182)
at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2171)
at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.executeReceiveMessage(AmazonSQSClient.java:1601)
at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.receiveMessage(AmazonSQSClient.java:1573)